# NPM error installing Mongoose - "Registry returned 404 for GET"

Tags: node.js, mongoose, npm

While newly installing mangoose driver inside my windows machine its throwing an error..

```
npm WARN package.json ravi@1.0.0 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json ravi@1.0.0 No README data
npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.10240
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "mongoose" "--save"
npm ERR! node v4.1.2
npm ERR! npm  v2.14.4
npm ERR! code E404

npm ERR! 404 Registry returned 404 for GET on http://registry.npmjs.org/clear/mongoose
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404 'mongoose' is not in the npm registry.
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)
npm ERR! 404 It was specified as a dependency of 'ravi'
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\users\ravi rathore\desktop\userStory\npm-debug.log
```

what should i do? thanks in advance

Comment: Just for completeness, could you include the command you're running? Is it `npm install mongoose`?

Comment: npm install mongoose --save

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is issue :

```
npm cache clean
```

If you still get the same error, please share with us your file :

```
package.json
```